# How can QED have degenerate vacua without superselection?

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, symmetry-breaking, asymptotics

This question is based on Andrew Strominger's lecture on the IR structure of field theories, in particular [Section 2.11](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448)

The usual story with spontaneous symmetry breaking is as follows. You have degenerate vacua. In and of itself, that's not special, because in principle the system can tunnel from one to the other, so the true vacuum is a superposition of all of these. However, in a field theory, there's no finite energy process that can do that, so the tunnelling amplitude is zero. We say the vacua are not just degenerate, but also superselected. The Hilbert space decomposes, and you can't superpose states living in the different factors.

Now, it turns in QED, the large gauge transformations are spontaneously broken. You have different vacua, differing by soft photons. However, as Strominger says, creating soft photons is a perfectly valid process, so there's no superselection, and the Hilbert space doesn't decompose. So why isn't the true vacuum some superposition of all of them?

Comment: Any theory with massless particles has superselection sectors. A transformation that creates soft photons is a change of the superselection sector.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Strominger explicitly says there are no superselection sectors for QED in the note I linked to.

Comment: In the usual story with SSB, the transition amplitude from one vacua to another is proportional to the volume of the spacetime which diverges in QFT thereby creating superselection sectors. Said differently, it takes an infinite amount of energy to overcome the transition barrier which is not possible to achieve in any physical process. On the other hand, the vacuum transitions associated with soft modes takes no energy (they are soft) at all and so is possible.

Comment: @Totofofo: In Footnote 8 Strominger says that he has a different notion of superselection sectors, which he never precisely explains. In QED, charged superselection sectors (in the sense of Herdegen hep-th/0412058, say) are necessarily direction dependent, hence break Lorentz invariance.